# Running sql scripts against an attached database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, mdf

I've got an MDF attached to an instance of Sql Server 2008 Express, and I need to run some sql scripts against it to generate tables, indexes, etc.

But I can't figure out how to get this to work.  If I load the scripts in Visual Studio, it only allows me to connect to the server and run it against a database.  I can't choose a different provider (Microsoft Sql Server Database File), so I can't select my MDF.

This leaves me the only option of running the script as individual queries, but that won't work as it appears it doesn't support TSQL CREATE statements.

How can I run my sql script against an attached database?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2005, after I attach a database, I can query - run scripts everything, what is that you are not able to do? Am I missing something?

Comment: If possible, try backup restore instead of attach db.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and here is what worked for me.

1. **Right-click** on the script and choose **Connection > Connect**
2. The server name and authentication should already be set for the local SQLEXPRESS instance.
3. Click the **Options** button
4. Click the **Additional Connection Parameters** tab
5. Paste in the the path to your database file using the following as a guide:

   **AttachDBFilename=C:\Path\To\Database\LocalData.mdf;database=LocalData;**
6. Click the **Connect** button

If you still have trouble connecting it may be because there is already an open connection.  Check Server Explorer and if connection is open, Right-click and choose Close Connection.

This process will also create a persistent connection as long as the SQL Script remains connected.  You will want to close the script or choose Right-click > Connection > Disconnect.

More information can be found at this question:
[EF4 Generate Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777963/ef4-generate-database)

Comment: Just as a note for step 5. you should use the full connection string for your database as expressed in the properties pane (or however you want to get the connection string). But the abbreviated syntax in your step 5 didn't work for me alone.

Comment: What if the database is on different machine? Again,  I think it's not right way to share the mdf file of db server.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean you have an local MDF file in Visual Studio (like an App_Data folder)?

You can use SQL Management Studio by connecting with the named pipe.

First, open up a new query in Visual Studio on the attached DB using their anoying query tool.  In the properties window, under ServerName, save that mini guid thats in the format of "your-PC-name\mini-guid".  Connect using Management Studio like this:

```
\\.\pipe\mini-guid-here\tsql\query
```

e.g.,

```
\\.\pipe\7789925E-DCAA-4A\tsql\query
```

You should see the filename listed under databases.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the script without need for SSMS? i.e. directly from VS?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [SqlCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility?

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter
>   Transact-SQL statements, system
>   procedures, and script files at the
>   command prompt, in Query Editor in
>   SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file
>   or in an operating system (Cmd.exe)
>   job step of a SQL Server Agent job.
>   This utility uses OLE DB to execute
>   Transact-SQL batches.

Comment: That'd be nice, but I don't think it works with attached databases (at least my attempts failed horribly).  Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i ran into the same problem when trying to import the contents of ASPNETDB into a different MDF here was how i did it:

1. Right click ASPNETDB.mdf in server explorer and publish to a .sql file.
2. open the .sql file using file - open. (not connected) will appear in the name.
3. Right click the attached target database and show properties (TargetDatabase.MDF)
4. Get the connection string out of the properties window..
   copy everything in the connection string after "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
5. Click the Execute Sql button (Ctrl + Shift + E)
6. in the server name type .\SQLEXPRESS
7. In the Additional Connection paramaters tab, paste the data you copied in step 4
8. Click connect and select the relevant target MDF file by its disk location from the list of files.
9. Click connect.
10. refresh the target DB