# Can LinqPad connect to an mdf file?

Tags: linqpad, mdf

Can LinqPad query from a loose mdf file?  How would it happen?

(Joe Albahari, are you out there?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Choose Linq to SQL. Then there's Attach Database File.
[image]

Comment: How do you "Linq to SQL"?