# Retrieving data from SQL Server Express database inside VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a new ASP.Net project in C#.  I have added a new database inside my App_Data folder called aspnetdb.mdf.  I have added the following connection string to my project:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    Integrated Security=SSPI;
    AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;
    User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I run my project, it retrieves the data just fine.

Now I want to write some new stored procedures.  So I open the query window to do so:

[image]

When I try to run a simple SELECT statement, I get an error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can return data from this table?  Keep in mind this is being done inside VS2010 and not in SQL Server as I don't have the full-blown SQL Server installed on my computer (although VS2010 installed some pieces of SQL Server 2008).

Comment: Check this Post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234244/how-to-run-an-sql-script-against-a-mdf-file

Comment: please ensure that your query editor is using the correct database. first run the use[your_database_name] query then execute select query

Comment: @Shetty - That worked at first, now I'm getting an error: Cannot open database "LocalData" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: When you clicked on connect, What username passwrod did u use? Did you use Windows Authentication?

Comment: Looks like the login which you have does not have permission to access the new db you have created (With logical name LocalData). This can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx

Comment: Turns out the database name becomes persistent, and so every time I run that fix from Shetty's link, I have to change the database name.  Weird.  Eventually I'm gonna run out of names...

Comment: Isnt it possible for you to have SQL server express edition installed on your local machine and attached the mdf file?